# Only last task runs!

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, task-parallel-library

I am in desperate to find a solution to my problem.

Following is the code which generates different task for each item in `List<AccountContactView>`.

```
List<AccountContactViewModel> selectedDataList
    = DataList.Where(
        dataList => (bool) dataList.GetType()
                                   .GetProperty("IsChecked")
                                   .GetValue(dataList, new object[0]) == true
      ).ToList();

this.IsEnabled = false;

Task validateMarked = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    foreach (AccountContactViewModel viewModel in selectedDataList)
    {
        if (viewModel != null)
        {
            Task validate = Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () => ValidateAccount(viewModel),
                (TaskCreationOptions)TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);
        }
    }
});

validateMarked.ContinueWith(x => this.IsEnabled = true);
```

Now my problem is when it runs, it only runs for the last item in the array. Any idea about what I am doing wrong?

I don't want to use `Parallel.ForEach` becuase it doesn't provide the necessary effect of parallelism to increase the progress bar based on completion of each task.

Comment: Someone asks this almost every day on SO. You are closing over a loop variable inside the loop. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx for details.

Comment: Minor point, but there's no need to call `.ToList()` on your `DataList` query if all you're going to do is enumerate it in a `foreach`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might be a lambda scope problem.

Have you tried to assign the viewModel to a local variable before passing it to the StartNew method

```
...
Task validateMarked = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    foreach (AccountContactViewModel viewModel in selectedDataList)
    {
        var localViewModel = viewModel;
        if (localViewModel != null)
        {
            Task validate = Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () => ValidateAccount(localViewModel),
                (TaskCreationOptions)TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);
        }
    }
});
...
```

Comment: Dude why do you have to assign viewModel to a local variable.  I've seen Resharper complain about this too many times.  +1 by the way.

Comment: Check out Eric Lippert article from the comments to the original question. He explains it well. Thx